# CentOS - Insufficient memory for the java runtime

Tags: jenkins, java-8, centos7

I want to install jenkins on my server, unfortunately, I can't run Java, i have this error :

`There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue`

[image: Error]

Result of `free -m` :
[image: free]
There is 2,7Go RAM free.

I set JAVA_OPTS :
`export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"`

So, I tried a lot of things, but it's impossible to start java...

If anyone has any ideas

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you're running into selinux enforcement. The quick solution is to set selinux to "permissive" via

```
setenforce 0
```

There's longer explanations that you can find if you search for "selinux openjdk os::commit_memory permission denied"

[How and why does "setenforce 0" allow Java 7 to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723474/how-and-why-does-setenforce-0-allow-java-7-to-run)

Comment: The answer that you linked to gives a *better* solution than setting SELinux to permissive.

Comment: Thx u soooo much >< !

Comment: You're welcome, but take into consideration what Stephen C said as well, there are more secure ways to get around your problem besides disabling selinux system-wide.

Comment: is there a solution to add java as a trust program? with a signature for exemple ?